# Hide "Site Actions" -> "View All Site Content" in a 2010 Publishing Site 

Tags: security-trimming, permissions

This is annoying. I've created a site, enabled the Publishing features, and added a couple people to the "Members" group that has Ready Only access.

When these users log in, they still see the "Site Actions" menu! When they click on the "Site Actions" menu, the only option given is "View Site Content"

[alt text http://img145.imageshack.us/img145/3139/siteactions.png](http://img145.imageshack.us/img145/3139/siteactions.png)

We are trying to reduce as much "SharePoint Noise" as possible, so we would only like the "Site Actions" menu to show for Admins.

The only way I've been able to hide this is to make the SiteActions control security trimmed, like so:

```
<Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" PermissionsString="ManageWeb">
    <SharePoint:SiteActions id="SiteActionsMenuMain" runat="server">
        ...
    </SharePoint:SiteActions>
</Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```

This seems a little dirty.

There has to be a better way to do this without having to edit the Master Page.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a way I can still hide "View All Site Content" option under site action?

Answer (score 6):

Not sure why you think your appoach is dirty. That's the right use of the SPSecurityTrimmedControl and you should not be afraid to use it that way!

In fact, MSDN suggest to use it for resolving issues like yours:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spsecuritytrimmedcontrol.aspx

and even more interesting use of it here:
http://blah.winsmarts.com/2008-5-Enhancing_the_SPSecurityTrimmedControl_-_Trimming_UI_on_any_critereon.aspx

Comment: Will this Not hide Site Actions to the owners of the site?

Comment: Using this control you can set PermissionString such that person with full permission (such as owner) can access the content but not others. See http://sympmarc.com/2008/12/31/spsecuritytrimmedcontrol-possible-values-for-permissionsstring/

Answer (score 2):

You could do this by editing the master page; find the SharePoint:SiteActions tag,, inside it you will find

```
<SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" id="MenuItem_ViewAllSiteContents",,
```

change `PermissionsString=""` property to:

```
"EnumeratePermissions,ManageWeb,ManageSubwebs,AddAndCustomizePages,ApplyThemeAndBorder,ManageAlerts,ManageLists,ViewUsageData"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<style>
 #ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_idNavLinkViewAll
 {
 Visibility:hidden;
 }
 </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps if you want to do it without changing code.

1. Click on "Site Actions -> Site Permissions"
2. On the ribbon select the "Permission Tools" tab and press the "Permission Levels" button under the "Manage" group on the far right
3. Click on the "Read" Permission Level
4. Scroll down to the "Personal Permissions" section and check the box for "Manage Personal Views - Create, change, and delete personal views of lists. Press the "Submit" button

Read full article [here](http://fixingsharepoint.blogspot.com/2015/04/how-to-hide-site-actions-in-sharepoint.html) and follow the steps. Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: We prefer not to post links as answers here, as they'll never be around forever. Rather, summarise the steps in the post, and provide a link as source.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this before using a CEWP and a quick script to control style.  Now keep in mind this for WSS/MOSS 2007.

```
<style>.ms-quicklaunchheader {display:none;}</style>
```

Make sure you hide the CEWP in webpart properties.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, that code is to hide the "View All Site Content" link in the Quick Launch navigation. The link I'm talking about resides in the Site Actions menu. I'm going to upload a pic for clarity.