# Hide Site Actions at the top of the page and the list tools on the toolbar for a specific permission group

Tags: ribbon

Hi I want to be able to hide the 'Site 'actions' button at the top of my sharepoint page as well as the List Tools in the ribbon. I have a code which removes these altogether but I want to remove these for only a specific permission group not everyone that visits the site.

Answer (score 0):

Cindy,

You can use [SPSecurityTrimmedControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spsecuritytrimmedcontrol.aspx) to put your logic inside this control to hide the Site Actions and other buttons!

Have a look at:
[Hide “Site Actions” -> “View All Site Content” in a 2010 Publishing Site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/6280/hide-site-actions-view-all-site-content-in-a-2010-publishing-site)
[SecurityTrimmedControl – An Indispensible Tool for your public facing SharePoint web site (and others)](http://whitepages.unlimitedviz.com/2010/05/securitytrimmedcontrol-an-indispensible-tool-for-your-public-facing-sharepoint-web-site-and-others/)

All possible permissions value are [Listed on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbasepermissions.aspx)