# How to hide "All Site content" from quick launch for Anonymous users in SharePoint foundation 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, permissions, quick-launch, anonymous-authentication

How to hide "All Site content" from quick launch for Anonymous users in SharePoint foundation 2010?
I referred many links but none of then worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this with the help of this link: [Hide view all Site Content](http://customlockdown.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 4):

The answer is quite simple.

Open the Master Page (Normally V4)
Find the following control :

```
<SharePoint:ClusteredSPLinkButton
                                    id="idNavLinkViewAllV4"
                                    runat="server"
                                    PermissionsString="ViewFormPages"
                                    NavigateUrl="~site/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx"
                                    ImageClass="s4-specialNavIcon"
                                    ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/fgimg.png"
                                    ImageWidth=16
                                    ImageHeight=16
                                    OffsetX=0
                                    OffsetY=0
                                    Text="<%$Resources:wss,quiklnch_allcontent_short%>"
                                    accesskey="<%$Resources:wss,quiklnch_allcontent_AK%>" />
```

and change it by adding this line at the bottom: [image]

Save and there you go.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the nav control in security trimmed control:

```
<Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" Permissions="AddDelPrivateWebParts">

**[ existing nav control ]**

<Triggers>
<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="WebPartAdder" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry...I am updating it once more...

we can easily upgrade the security to different security level. For example, if we change the PermissionsString=”ManageWeb” then only users who have this permission level (site admins) will see the View All Site Content link.

” AccessKey=”<%$Resources:wss,quiklnch_allcontent_AK%>”/>

Comment: This does not really answer the core question. The Poster wants to hide ONLY for anonymous users.

Comment: The master page already has <SharePoint:ClusteredSPLinkButton statement.Also i want to hide it only for anonymous users.

Comment: I changed PermissionsString=”ManageWeb” but "All site content" still visible for anonymous access.

Comment: Have a look at the different permission..http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbasepermissions.aspx

Comment: Also have look at this...it might help you..http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/6280/hide-site-actions-view-all-site-content-in-a-2010-publishing-site