# Sharepoint Site Content Gear

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, permissions, site

I need to hide and avoid **reader users** (users view *just read permission* on the site) to view the **site content page** (*viewlsts.aspx*)
How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You should edit master page and add `AuthenticationRestrictions` to `ClusteredSPLinkButton`

[How to hide "All Site content" from quick launch for Anonymous users in SharePoint foundation 2010?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/76318/how-to-hide-all-site-content-from-quick-launch-for-anonymous-users-in-sharepoi)

Another option is to hide the link from Quick Launch.

http://www.sharepointsiren.com/2014/02/sharepoint-hide-all-site-content-link.html

Still if the user know the URL, they can manually type and access the link.

Comment: I have to hide to the Reader Users not the Anonymous