# How to restrict _layouts pages in SharePoint site?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I have to restrict _layouts pages from SharePoint site for all users(**except one group**). 
Please suggest me the solution. I am using sharepoint 2013 on premises.

Comment: all layouts pages?

Comment: Yes, All _layout pages @jpussacq

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend not to, since you will effectively restrict users from viewing Sitce Contents of the site, which is located here: http://SPSite/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx

But if you have to, add the groups you want to restrict to a new Policy for the web application, and deny "view application pages,..." which is explaind in detail in the article [Preventing authenticated visitors from browsing system pages](https://blog.mastykarz.nl/preventing-authenticated-visitors-browsing-system-pages/)

Comment: as speaking of Site Contents: is there a way of disabling the "site contents" link to appear on the left side navigation bar?

Comment: @Bucki See [Hide “Site Actions” -> “View All Site Content” in a 2010 Publishing Site](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/6280/6382)

Comment: Thank you @BennySkogberg. I can restrict access to all users but, how to allow access to one group and user policy is not allowing sharepoint groups

Comment: @vinodkumar Try to grant access the same way with your special group. It should work even if they are in conflict. Otherwise you have to specify the users to two groups which have Deny Access and Grant Access respectively. Maybe you can filter this out in your Active Directory?

Comment: @Benny the only thing I am ok with is the css style and changing permission levels; everything else (coding) is beyond my knowledge. I was hopping there is a setting to turn off, at least from the left side nav.  Thanks though

Comment: @Bucki This is only markup, which you should be familiar with if you know css :-). Just make sure you create a copy first so you can restore the files if you break something!

Comment: @Benny easier said than done :) thanks, I might find the courage to try it out some-day.

Answer (score 0):

There is the ability to restrict access to most all capabilities in SharePoint using the Permission Levels.

You can strip out all of the permission to the Site and Lists to limit what your users can see.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721640.aspx